# Retrieving message from Flask socket raises "Invalid left-hand side in assignment"

Tags: javascript, socket.io, flask-socketio

I'm trying to create a channel I can join using Flask socketio and Javascript.

All of my debug statements are firing, indicating that everything is initializing, but when I try to capture the message emitted from my Flask/socket-io route, which I assume executes the actual room change, I get `Uncaught ReferenceError: Invalid left-hand side in assignment` in my console referring to the line in my JS file `let message = data.msg;` in the section:

```
    socket.on('status', data => {
        let message = data.msg;
        document.querySelectorAll('#messages') += message;
    });
```

I tried writing `data.msg` various ways (e.g., with backticks, like this ${data.msg} surrounded by backticks as if part of a formatted string, etc), but nothing worked. I've read the docs, and they were sparse on details. There appear to be zero examples of how to do this effectively on the web. Most people seem to favor node.js, but I'm a Flask guy.

How can I join my room, and chat only in that room? I'll need to allow users to create as many as they want.

**Here's the route in Flask:**

```
@socketio.on('join')
def on_join(data):
    username = data['username']
    room = data['room']
    join_room(room)
    emit("status", {'msg': username + 'has joined the room'}, room=room)
```

**Here's the accompanying JS:**

```
var socket = io.connect(location.protocol + '//' + document.domain + ':' + location.port);
if (!socket) console.log("Socket not connected!");

socket.on('connect', () => {
    console.log("socket connected");
    // after socket connect, configure channel button
    document.querySelectorAll('button').forEach(button => {
        button.onclick = () => {
            console.log("button click fired!");
            let username = localStorage["login"]
            let room = button.dataset.room;
            console.log("ChannelName" + room);
            socket.emit("join", {'username':username, "room":room});
        };
    });

    socket.on('status', data => {
        console.log("JOINED!")
        let message = data.msg;
        document.querySelectorAll('#messages') += message;
    });
```

Note, the error occurs right **before** assignment to the `#message` div.

**EDIT**
Unpacking the error reveals multiple references to the minified JS file flask socket-io requires. It is in the `<head>` section of `layout.html`. Placement in the `<body>` caused serious errors impeded development of all socket-related functionality.

```
messages:134 Uncaught ReferenceError: Invalid left-hand side in assignment
    at r.socket.on.data (messages:134)
    at r.n.emit (socket.io.min.js:1)
    at r.onevent (socket.io.min.js:1)
    at r.onpacket (socket.io.min.js:1)
    at n.<anonymous> (socket.io.min.js:1)
    at n.emit (socket.io.min.js:1)
    at n.ondecoded (socket.io.min.js:1)
    at s.<anonymous> (socket.io.min.js:1)
    at s.n.emit (socket.io.min.js:1)
    at s.add (socket.io.min.js:2)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not valid: `document.querySelectorAll('#messages') += message;`

`document.querySelectorAll('#messages')` Would give you a list of DOM elements.

Also, element id's are supposed to be unique, so you should probably be using `document.querySelector('#messages')` so retrieve just one element, and not a list.

You can not add/concat text to an element directly this way. You probably are looking for something like `document.querySelector('#messages').innerHTML += message;`